# Google Scholar Profile of Department or College

Tags: google-scholar

I found a google scholar profile that represents one of the academic departments of a university. All articles published by faculty working in that department since long time are listed in that google scholar profile. How is it possible to link all papers from multiple people working in same department? That is just so cool and I wish I can know so other departments can follow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as far as I understood, you can add any paper to your Scholar profile, even those where you are not listed as an author.

On the other hand, while this idea may seem attractive to you, note that Scholar is not intended to work like that. It is meant just for personal profiles. Also, there is a possible problem regarding personal data and mixing up data on citations and H-index which Google estimates for all involved. I would advise against such a departmental profile.